# Change a image of a selected row in a tableview

Tags: javascript, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have a tableview with several rows. I need to change the image on the clicked row.

My code:

```
function ConstruyoMenuLateral(){

  var db = Ti.Database.open('Termolink');
  var rows = db.execute('SELECT * FROM TablaAuxiliar ORDER BY TablaAuxiliar.Nombre');

  NRegistros=ComprueboRegBD();

  var i;

  for (i=0;i<NRegistros;i++){
    TablaNombreTermostatos[i]= rows.field(2);

    var nuevaRow=Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({height:80}); 
    var titulo1=Ti.UI.createLabel({
        id: "NombreTerm",
        text: TablaNombreTermostatos[i],
        color: "black" ,
        textAlign: Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_LEFT, 
        left:20,
        top:5
    });
    var boton4=Ti.UI.createImageView({
        id: "BotonTerm",
        top: 15,
        left: 310,          
        image: "/Teclado open.png"
    });

    nuevaRow.add(titulo1);
    nuevaRow.add(boton4);

    $.MenuLateral.appendRow(nuevaRow);
    rows.next();
  }     

  db.close();       
}

$.MenuLateral.addEventListener('click', function(e){

    if (e.source.id!="BotonTerm") AbrePrincipal();
    else{
        if (EmisorSeleccionado==e.index) {
            $.MenuLateral(e.index).boton4.image="/Teclado close.png";
            EmisorSeleccionado=999;//ya estaba seleccionado, quito selección                
        }   
        else {
            //
            $.MenuLateral(e.index).boton4.image="/Teclado open.png";
        }
    }

    ActualizaPantalla();
});
```

When I click on `BotonTerm`, I need to change the image of this row.
But `$.MenuLateral(e.index).boton4.image="/Teclado close.png";` crashes.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get clicked row to:

```
var rowSelected=e.row;
```

and update using the method [updateRow](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableView-method-updateRow)